# JavaScript: why does changing an argument variable change the `arguments` "array"?

Tags: javascript

Consider:

```
> function hello(what) {
.     what = "world";
.     return "Hello, " + arguments[0] + "!";
. }
> hello("shazow")
"Hello, world!"
```

Why does changing the value of `what` change the value of `arguments[0]`?

Answer (score 13):

> *"Why does changing the value of `what` change the value of `arguments[0]`?"*

Because that's how it's designed to work. The formal parameters are directly mapped to the indices of the arguments object.

That is *unless* you're in *strict mode*, and your environment supports it. Then updating one doesn't effect the other.

```
function hello(what) {
    "use strict"; // <-- run the code in strict mode
    what = "world";
    return "Hello, " + arguments[0] + "!";
}
hello("shazow"); // "Hello, shazow!"
```

Comment: Oh… In that case: why is it designed to work that way? And is that design documented anywhere? (not that I don't trust you, of course, I'd just like a bit more detail)

Comment: Oh, wait, here we go: "NOTE 1" in *10.6 Arguments Object* of http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: @DavidWolever: The language is document in the ECMAScript specification. Strict mode was introduced in ECMAScript 5.

Comment: @DavidWolever—for convenience, there is an [HTML version of ES5](http://es5.github.com/) on github.

Comment: A little lighter reading than the official spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: @RobG oh, that is significantly more convenient. Thanks.

Comment: @jfriend00 I might simply be blind… But I don't see any reference to this behaviour in that document =\

Comment: Look in [§10.5 Declaration Binding Instantiation](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5) step 7 b and c, note that in non-strict mode, *SetMutableBinding* concrete method is set using `false`. The specs are written in a way that if you don't know the answer, it can be very difficult to find things.