# Why can't I access arguments.callee in this sloppy-mode function?

Tags: javascript, arguments

I am trying to access the `arguments.callee` property in the simple function below, but I couldn't since the function throws an error.

```js
function foo(a = 50, b) {
  console.log(arguments.callee);
}

foo(10, 50);
```

**Why is this happening?** It seems that the function is running in strict mode, but how is that possible since I didn't mention the statement `'use strict';`

I am running this on Chrome.

Comment: Are you in a module? ie, do you use `import` or `export`? If so, then you are automatically in strict mode.

Comment: It could be that modern browsers are automatically using strict mode?

Comment: @NicholasTower no. Nothing like that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think so as well, but weirdly I couldn't find any resource mentioning that.

Comment: Are you using Typescript?  Running in Chrome console?  There are a few ways you can automatically be in strict mode without specifying it.  Please add details about your runtime environment if the answer you're looking for is _why_ it's in strict mode.

Comment: [Getting the same error in Chrome when running in sloppy mode](https://jsfiddle.net/ou68q7j5/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `arguments` object is automatically created like in strict mode if you are using advanced (modern, ES6+) syntax in your function declaration - in your case it's the default parameter initialiser. The function is not actually strict mode - e.g. you can still use a `with` statement in there, but the `arguments` object is no longer backwards-compatible with pre-ES5 code.

See the [note on *FunctionDeclarationInstantiation*](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation):

> A mapped argument object is only provided for non-strict functions that don't have a rest parameter, any parameter default value initializers, or any destructured parameters.

Apart from no longer having a `.callee`, it doesn't reflect assignments to the parameter variables either (which was always rather surprising, see [JavaScript: why does changing an argument variable change the `arguments` "array"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10221009/1048572) or [Changing JavaScript function's parameter value using arguments array not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54323086/1048572)).

Basically `arguments.callee` was deprecated with ES5, but for backward compatibility the language can only opt out of providing it when you opt in to modern syntax, like using strict mode or non-simple parameter declarations.

Comment: Can u point to any reference/resource. I think this is exactly what's happening.

Comment: So u mean that the function is not actually in strict mode, but rather only `arguments` is being treated as if it is in strict mode?

Comment: Wow, this was just what I needed. Thanks :)